# Spark TextInput incomplete value using Barcode Reader

Tags: apache-flex, air

working with Flex4 AIR app, using this component I get data from the barcode reader,

```
<s:TextInput id="barcode" enter="showBarcode()"/>
```

Then for handle the enter event, wich is automatically triggered when reader finishes its reading

```
private function showBarcode():void{
   Alert.show(barcode.text);
}
```

Ok, very simple. But my problem is: the text showed in the Alert Box is incomplete, it misses one or two digits (last) or it just shows the entire text in the TextInput component (correct view)

I already test my BC reader using the notepad, and it's fine.

I have tested same code using MX components in Flex3 web app, and there's no problem.

Some help will be appreciated.

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "enter" try listening to the onKeyUp event.

You'll have to figure out the appropriate end of line character read in from the bar code scanner.  But, just key in on that and do your alert that way; otherwise do nothing.

Comment: I try your suggestion using keyUp="showBarcode(event)". The result is the same.

I believe this could be a bug related to the input buffer, I don't know.

Tnx

Comment: Interesting.  It is easy to believe an input buffer would be a factor here.  Have you tried the mx:TextInput in the Flex 4 SDK?

Comment: you'll actually want to do keyDown, not keyUp (think about holding down a key in the textInput).  We use barcode scanners here on many machines (listening for ctrl-y, the first character on our barcodes, to trigger certain actions in barcodeManager that becomes part of the display list... all works perfectly).

Comment: @flextras You're right.. I just switched to mx:TextInput in the Flex 4 SDK and now it works perfectly.. Thanks!

This could be interesting for the development team..

Comment: @Gusty Must be an oddity in the Spark TextInput.  @Jeremy I'm wondering why keyDown or keyUp would fire when using a bar code reader at all.  Techincally no keys were pressed.  I'm guessing Flash Player can't tell where the input is coming from?

Comment: @El Howser -- if it is a generic barcode scanner, it is a usb device that is recognized as a keyboard, complete with OS keyboard presses. There is a chance that the thing has an application that acts as a proxy to the system... but I believe 99% of the barcode scanners that have been made in the last 10 years act as keyboards.

Comment: We discovered this same oddity where I work. Has anyone reported this to Adobe then?

Answer (score 3):

We ran into the same problem and we ended up saving the chars received from the barcode scanner in a buffer instead of accessing the TextInput text property. We always received the chars in the correct order but, with the Spark TextInput, the text property was sometimes scrambled.

```
<s:TextInput id="barcode" keyDown="barcode_keyDownHandler(event)" />
```

This is the buffer we used and these are the relevant functions:

```
private var textBuffer:ArrayList = new ArrayList();

protected function getTextBufferContent():String
{
    var content:String="";
    for (var i:int = 0; i < textBuffer.length; i++)
    {
        content=content.concat(textBuffer.getItemAt(i));
    }
    return content;
}

protected function handleKeyboardEnter():void
{
    var barcodeScan:String=getTextBufferContent();
    textBuffer.removeAll();
    if (barcodeScan != "")
    {
        Alert.show(barcodeScan);
    }
}

protected function barcode_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace("barcode_keyDownHandler: " + event.keyCode + " " + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));               
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        handleKeyboardEnter();
    }
    else textBuffer.addItem(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
}
```

The mx:TextInput also worked, but we wanted to keep the Spark component.

Answer (score 0):

Is text at least displayed as you would expect in Spark TextInput by using the same workflow with barcode reader as shown in this video "Flash Nicey Nice With HID" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEw0RB-Uj00 ?

Anyway, I do not think Adobe Flash player supports officially other HID devices rather then keyboard or mouse.

Thus I would not expect Adobe engineers to make Spark TextInput compliant with your barcode reader input any time soon.

Comment: Just an idea.

Try to listen for "change" event for Spark TextInput and inside the event listener check if the last text character is Keyboard.ENTER symbol > this will signal that the whole text is read from the barcode reader.

Comment: The BC reader acts as a regular keyboard, works perfectly listening to the "enter" event on either mx:TextInput and s:TextInput, the problem is related to the input data of the Spark component only, it behaves strange, the same data displayed in the field isn't available (sometimes partially) for AS use immediately after any event occurs (enter, change, keyUp, ..). The MX component works as spected for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this same thing where I work, with barcode scanning in Flex 4 / Spark. There are two workarounds we found.

The **first** is to use the old "Halo" TextInput control (`<mx:TextInput />`). You can do this even in a Flex 4 project.

The **second** method, is to keep the "Spark" TextInput control, but to use a very short Timer in your keyUp or keyDown event to let the text property be fully filled with the barcode scan data -- I don't know exactly why this works, but it does. And you get to keep all of the benefits of the Spark control/skinning. So the original poster's example could be fixed if it became:

```
<s:TextInput id="barcode" keyDown="showBarcode(event)"/>
```

and

```
private function showBarcode(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {

    var t:Timer = new Timer(10, 1); // 10ms
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function():void { 
        Alert.show(barcode.text);
    });
    t.start();
}
```

**Bonus:** 
If you didn't want to use this Timer all over your code in event handlers, you could make a utility function for it in a `Barcoder.as` class like so:

```
public static function checkScan(evt:KeyboardEvent, callback:Function):void 
{
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        var t:Timer = new Timer(10, 1); // 10 ms
        t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function():void { callback(); } );
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Then, if you had two separate barcode fields, with two separate handlers (`bc1_handler()` and `bc2_handler()`) your mxml would be something like:

```
<s:TextInput id="barcode1" keyDown="Barcoder.checkScan(event, bc1_handler)" />
<s:TextInput id="barcode2" keyDown="Barcoder.checkScan(event, bc2_handler)" />
```